# Qiskit: rounding with get_statevector does not work?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am trying to follow some tutorials for Qiskit and came to the point where I wanted to get some statevector containing $1/\sqrt{2}$ with the following line of code:

`outputstate = result.get_statevector(circ, decimals=3)`

By specifying the option `decimals=3`, it should round the numerical value in the statevector to 0.707. However, it does not do that. Instead, what is displayed is `0.70710678+0.j`as it apparently fails to round.

What could be the problem causing this? Or how else could I resolve this issue to get nicer looking results when displayed?

Comment: Which version are you using? It seems that problem was solved in qiskit-terra 0.17 https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/5428

Comment: I just updated to qiskit-terra 0.17.4 and now it is working properly again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it could be a bug so it might be worth checking the [Qiskit repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra) to raise an issue or see if anyone else has spotted it already.

If you are simply looking to format the results, you can use Python's f strings, for example `print(f'{outputstate:.3f}')` would print `outputstate` to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the Qiskit repo. It was indeed already solved there!